# Concurrency within actors using Futures

Tags: scala, akka, actor

I am wondering if there is a better way to handle async initialization of values within an Actor. Actors of course are thread safe when inside the actor, but using Futures throws a wrinkle in that (and you have to make sure you don't close over `context` or `sender`) Consider the following:

```
class ExampleActor(ref1: ActorRef, ref2: ActorRef) extends Actor {

  implicit val ec = context.dispatcher

  val promise1 = Promise[Int]
  val promise2 = Promise[Int]

  def receive = {
    case Request1.Response(x) => promise1.success(x)
    case Request2.Response(y) => promise2.success(y)
    case CombinedResponse(x, y) => x + y
  }

  promise1.future foreach { x =>
    promise2.future foreach { y =>
      self ! CombinedResponse(x, y) 
    }
  }

  ref1 ! Request1
  ref2 ! Request2
}
```

Is there a better/more idiomatic way of handling parallel requests like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually don't need futures to handle multi-part response:

```
var x: Option[Int] = None
var y: Option[Int] = None

def receive = {
  case Request1.Response(x) => x = Some(x); checkParts
  case Request2.Response(y) => y = Some(y); checkParts
}

def checkParts = for {
   xx <- x
   yy <- y
} parent ! xx + yy
```

By the way, you may use for-comprehension in the same way even with futures.

More functional way to manage actor's state:

```
case class Resp1(x: Int)
case class Resp2(y: Int)
case class State(x: Option[Int], y: Option[Int])

class Worker(parent: ActorRef) extends Actor {
  def receive = process(State(None, None))

  def process(s: State): Receive = edge(s) andThen { sn => 
    context become process(sn)
    for {
       xx <- sn.x
       yy <- sn.y
    } parent ! xx + yy //action
  }

  def edge(s: State): PartialFunction[Any, State] = { //managing state
    case Resp1(x) => s.copy(x = Some(x))
    case Resp2(y) => s.copy(y = Some(y))
  }

}
```

Reusing the actor instead of creating a future is better because `promise.success` actually does a non-managable side-effect by submitting task into an executor, so it's not a pure functional way. Actor's state is better, as  side-effect inside an actor is always consistent with other actor's - they're applied step-by-step and only in response to some message. So you may see the actor just as `fold` on infinite collection; state and messages (also infinite) sent by actor may be seen just as fold's accumulator.

Talking about Akka, its actors have some kind of IoC features like automatical exception handling (through supervising), which isn't available inside future. In your case, you have to introduce an additional composite message to return into the actor's IoC-context. Adding any other action than `self ! CombinedResponse(x, y)` (which, for example, may be accidentally done by some other developer to implement some workaround) is unsafe.

Comment: I wrote something very similar with: `def receive = initializing(None, None); def initializing(req1: Option[Request1], req2: Option[Request2]): Receive ...; context.become(initialized(...)); def initialized(req1: Request1, req2: Request2): Receive`. You beat me to it. Nice answer

Comment: This is a really great answer. Followup question - what are the benefits of this over using Promises and Futures, other than not having to worry about publishing the context to a different thread?

Comment: what is someRef? Jeff using Options instead of futures doesn't generate new threads.

Comment: Akka is multiplexing threads all over the place, so using `Futures` and running on a separate thread isn't necessarily an issue. Now, if the overhead of context switching is higher than using the functional approach, now that would be a reason to avoid `Futures`.

Comment: Following up on this, but does the "more functional" way actually work? Looking at the code, your `andThen` function is wrapping the parameters of `process`. This won't reflect the changes that occur in `edge` when it calls `become`, so they will reflect the old state

Comment: @Andrew Cassidy someRef is the actor, that actually needs `x + y` result

Comment: About benefits - executing on separate thread maybe an issue as this thread may be executed in parallell with actor, and in general case you have no sequentiality guarantees here (excluding situations when you chaining futures, but then you can even model actor, so it's not the case). It's may be fine for smallapplication, but it's hard to control them in big complex system. For example - it's hard to manage exceptions inside future. And no combined reponse here - it may cause some memory overhead (not always negligible) as it's placed into the mailbox for a while.

Comment: yes, you're right about `andThen`, corrected the code a bit.

Comment: Oh and also `promise.success` actually does a non-managable side-effect - so it's not a pure functional way. actor's state is better, as  side-effect inside an actor are always consistent with other actor's - they're applied step-by-step and only in response to some message. So you may see the actor just as `fold` on infinite collection, state and messages (also infinite) sent by actor may be seen just as fold's accumulator.